# Comparar datagridview VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Tenho um form com 3 datagridview.

O dgv1 e o dgv2 carregarão na coluna 01 um código de produto. O dgv1 é o mestre, tem todos produtos. Já o dgv2 terá só alguns desses produtos.

Como compara-los e carregar no dgv3 apenas os produtos do dgv1 que não aparecem no dgv2?

Resumindo, gostaria que o terceiro datagridview resultasse a diferença entre os dois anteriores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grosso modo, seria isto:

```
Sub Extrair(dgv1 As DataGridView, dgv2 As DataGridView, dgv3 As DataGridView)
    Dim todosOsCodigos = dgv1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Select(
        Function(dgvr) dgvr.Cells(1).Value).ToArray

    Dim codigos_dgv2 = dgv2.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Select(
        Function(dgvr) dgvr.Cells(1).Value).ToArray

    Dim codigos_restantes = todosOsCodigos.Except(codigos_dgv2).ToArray

    For Each dgvr As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.Rows
        If codigos_restantes.Contains(dgvr.Cells(1).Value) Then
            dgv3.Rows.Add(dgvr.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(
                Function(dgvc) dgvc.Value).ToArray)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Mas não é a melhor forma de fazer isso. Se os dados dos DataGridViews vêm de DataSources, seria preferível você fazer essa análise diretamente nos objetos fonte dos dados.

Answer (score 0):

**Respondendo a sua pergunta**

Basta percorrer a primeira DataGridView, comparando item a item com a segunda DataGridView. Se o item não existir, ele será adicionado no DGV3.

```
Dim exite As Boolean
For Each colunas1 As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.DataGridView.Rows
    exite = False
    For Each colunas2 As DataGridViewRow In dgv2.DataGridView.Rows
        if colunas1.Cells(0).Value = colunas2.Cells(0).Value then
            existe = True
            exit For
        end if 
    Next  
    if Not exite then
        'Adiciona linha no DGV3
    end if
Next
```

**Melhor solução na minha opnião**

Acho melhor você fazer isto quando você buscar os dados, seja no DataSource ou em outro modo. Pois evita de ficar fazendo estas comparações com os DataGridViews.